# What is causing such delay of loading my website?

Tags: html, wordpress, plugins, pageload

I use divi and I created landing page. After finish I figured that it loads like 20 seconds for visitors! There is link to this page [my page](https://universeoflight.xyz/alchemia-przebudzenia-promo/) , I guess it's some kind of block or plugin but I can't figure out which. Any help? Struggling with this for hours.. Thanks.

Comment: https://tools.pingdom.com/#5b928605ed000000

Comment: My whole page universeoflight.xyz works well but the landing page :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you are loading a lot of content, images, videos, ... try to implement some lazyload for images & videos.
- there are a lot of errors in the console.log
- your hosting is slow

Try to fix these. Even Lighthouse times out on that page.

Regards Tom

Comment: I will try to fix thos

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with the hosting, because TTFB (Time To First Byte) is like 13 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I have runned a website speed check from GTMetrix, you can see the actual test here:

• https://gtmetrix.com/reports/universeoflight.xyz/xwhl9MyP

I am able to see on the "PageSpeed" and "YSlow" tab that there are few "SERVER" listed optimization recommendations:

> Leverage browser caching
>
> Add Expires headers

These recommendations can be easily fulfilled with good WordPress cache plugin. Recently, I have started using [WPCacheOn](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpcacheon/) on all of the websites I am managing and I am very happy with it. Simply install and activate the [WPCacheOn](https://wpcacheon.io/) and no further configurations or settings are needed for faster website.

Additionally another thing you should look into is the "[lazy load](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/lazy+load/)" optimization. You can also consider using CDN service such as [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/). Ensure that you are using the latest PHP version for optimal performance and security. Another good practice is to lower the images size. In the "Waterfall" tab in GTMetrix you can see that there is the next image:

https://universeoflight.xyz/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/19742.jpg

Which is 2 MB. If you reduce that image size this will also improve the overall loading of of your landing page.